# How to get day start date in seconds based on current date in seconds

Tags: c#

As in the title, I get the current date in seconds and I need to get the start of the day also in seconds, example function

```
private long? getStartOfDay(long? dateVal){
    return ...
}
```

date with 0 number of seconds will return midnight Jan 1 1970

Comment: "Date in seconds" - what is the datum for this? By which I mean: What date/time corresponds to zero seconds?

Comment: midnight Jan 1 1970,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
    private static long? getStartOfDay(long? dateVal) {
        return dateVal - dateVal % 86400L;
    }
```

Just truncating down to nearest multiple of `24 * 60 * 60`.

Will not work with negative values, so either include a check that will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, or change to `ulong`.

Comment: I wondered about that.. Wasn't quite sure whether leap seconds had any bearing on doing it as a straight modulo though

Comment: @CaiusJard Leap seconds are not included in the Unix second count. It measures the number of nonleap seconds only.

Answer (score 1):

You are working with *Unix* date. To get `DateTime` from `seconds`:

```
 double seconds = ...

 // .Date to get rid of TimeOfDay (Hour, Minute, Second) component 
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(seconds).Date;
```

Or if you want to get local time `Date`

```
 DateTime startDate = DateTime.UnixEpoch.AddSeconds(seconds).ToLocalTime().Date;
```

To get `seconds` from `DateTime`:

```
 DateTime myDate = ...

 var seconds = (myDate.ToUniversalTime() - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Would it be an optimization to just `dateVal - DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTime(dateVal).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds` ?

Comment: @Caius Jard: your code `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTime(dateVal)` can well be a (micro) optimization - several (nano?) seconds faster, several bytes shorter. I've tried to follow the question - "number of seconds will return midnight Jan 1 1970" - manually subtract `1 Jan 1970` and show how can it be done.